# Derangements and unit fractions

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, diophantine-equations, permutations, unit-fractions

Motivated by a recent [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315648/) of [Zhi-Wei Sun](https://mathoverflow.net/users/124654/zhi-wei-sun) and its nice answer by [Zhao Shen](https://mathoverflow.net/users/131542/zhao-shen), here are two related questions.

Let $S_n$ be the group of permutations on $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

a. For each $n \ge 6$, is there some $\pi \in S_n$ such that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k - \pi(k)} = 3?$$

b. For each $n \ge 8$, is there some $\pi \in S_n$ such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k - \pi(k)} = 0?$$

In order for the sums to be well-defined/finite, the permutations must have no fixed points, i.e., the questions are looking for derangements with certain properties.

Here are data found using Mathematica on the number of derangements in $S_n$ for which $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k - \pi(k)}$ is a nonnegative integer.  (By symmetry, negative sums match the positive sums.)

\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrr}
n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ \hline
2 & 1 \\
3 & 0 \\
4 & 5 \\
5 & 0 \\
6 & 53 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
7 & 0 & 12 & 0 & 1\\
8 & 859 & 53 & 40 & 27 & 2\\
9 & 176 & 421 & 23 & 49 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
10 & 20329 & 1593 & 1366 & 684 & 120 & 3 & 3 & 2\\
11 & 7410 & 16025 & 4544 & 2714 & 262 & 38 & 85 & 0\\
\end{array}

For example, $(3,1,2,6,4,5) \in S_6$ satisfies (a) since
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-3} + \frac{1}{2-1} + \frac{1}{3-2}+\frac{1}{4-6}+\frac{1}{5-4}+\frac{1}{6-5}  \\
= \frac{1}{-2} + 1 + 1+\frac{1}{-2}+1+1=3
\end{align*}
and $(2,6,5,8,4,9,1,7,3)\in S_9$ satisfies (b) since
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-2} + \frac{1}{2-6} + \frac{1}{3-5}+\frac{1}{4-8}+\frac{1}{5-4}+\frac{1}{6-9} +\frac{1}{7-1}+\frac{1}{8-7}+\frac{1}{9-3} \\
= -1 + \frac{1}{-4} + \frac{1}{-2}+\frac{1}{-4}+1+\frac{1}{-3} +\frac{1}{6}+1+\frac{1}{6}=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: For question b, the answer is yes for n even by any appropriate involution. It might be useful to examine the answers for 9. I suspect each one can be extended to higher n.  Similarly, once any sum is achieved for two n of different parity, all higher n should achieve that sum by extending the solution.  Gerhard "Knows How To Add Zero" Paseman, 2018.11.24.

Comment: Completing the answer for b): as soon as there is an odd $n$ for which such derangement exists, it also exosts for all larger odd $n$, as you may supplement by independent transpositiobs. Tbe same holds for a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, let me give an answer using the ideas of Gerhard and Ilya in the comments.

Proposition: Suppose $\pi \in S_n$ satisfies $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k-\pi(k)} = r$ for some real number $r$.  Then, using cycle notation, $\tau = \pi (n+2, n+1) \in S_{n+2}$ satisfies $\sum_{k=1}^{n+2} \frac{1}{k-\tau(k)} = r$.

Proof: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+2} \frac{1}{k-\tau(k)} = \left[\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k-\pi(k)}\right] + \frac{1}{n+1-(n+2)} + \frac{1}{n+2-(n+1)} = r - 1 + 1 = r.$$

Therefore the problem, for any fixed sum, reduces to finding initial permutations of $S_n$ for odd and even values of $n$.  For instance, to verify that, for each $n \ge 7$, there is some $\pi \in S_n$ with $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k-\pi(k)} = 1$, it suffices to verify that the derangements (in list form) $(3,6,7,1,2,5,4) \in S_7$ and $(2, 4, 6, 3, 8, 5, 1, 7) \in S_8$ satisfy the condition.  (I found these using Mathematica.)

For another question in this vein, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316204).