# On the permanent $\text{per}[i^{j-1}]_{1\le i,j\le p-1}$ modulo $p^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences, permanent

Let $p$ be an odd prime. It is well-known that
$$\det[i^{j-1}]_{1\le i,j\le p-1}=\prod_{1\le i<j\le p-1}(j-i)\not\equiv0\pmod p.$$
I'm curious about the behavior of the permanent  $\text{per}[i^{j-1}]_{1\le i,j\le p-1}$ modulo powers of $p$. This leads me to formulate the following conjecture on the basis of my computation.

**Conjecture**. If $p$ is a Fermat prime, then 
$$\text{per}[i^{j-1}]_{1\le i,j\le p-1}\equiv\frac{p-1}2!\ p\pmod{p^2}.$$
If $n\not\equiv2\pmod4$ and $n$ is not a Fermat prime, then 
$$\text{per}[i^{j-1}]_{1\le i,j\le n-1}\equiv 0\pmod{n^2}.$$
For $n\equiv2\pmod4$, we have 
$$\text{per}[i^{j-1}]_{1\le i,j\le n-1}\not\equiv 0\pmod{n}.$$

QUESTION: Is the above conjecture true?

Now I show that $\text{per}[i^{j-1}]_{1\le i,j\le p-1}\equiv0\pmod p$ for any odd prime $p$. (It is easy to see that this implies that $n\mid \text{per}[i^{j-1}]_{1\le i,j\le n}$ for all $n=3,4,\ldots$.) Let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$. Then
$$\text{per}[i^{j-1}]_{1\le i,j\le p-1}\equiv\sum_{\sigma\in S_{p-1}}\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}g^{i(\sigma(i)-1)}=\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}g^{-i}\times\text{per}[g^{ij}]_{1\le i,j\le p-1}\pmod p.$$
Thus we may appy my argument in [the related question 316836](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/316836) to get that $\text{per}[i^{j-1}]_{1\le i,j\le p-1}\equiv0\pmod p$ since the order of $g$ mod $p$ is the even number $p-1$.

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Great questions ... Do you know if this problem has links with the problem "P=NP" ??

Comment: why on earth would there be such a connection?

Answer (score 4):

The $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ part of the conjecture fails for $n=18$, when the permanent is divisible even by $18^7$, but not by $18^8$.

**ADDED.** The *"$n\not\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ and $n$ is not a Fermat prime"* part fails for $n=29$, when the permanent $\,\equiv 464\pmod{29^2}$.